# View source code started to show all code in 1 line , how to change it?

Tags: google-chrome

[image]

On the screen you can see that all html code started to be shown in 1 line, but in the past it was shown as general html, how can I change it ( google chrome ) ?

```
view-source:http://localhost:5000/en/promo/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is minified HTML, produced in order to reduce file size. You can convert this back to "normal" via any of the various unminifiers/beautifiers found online such as https://beautifier.io.